# Can the chain rule and product rule be derived using Lagrange's algebraic approach to calculus?

Tags: calculus, rational-functions

So a while ago I learned about an algebraic approach to calculus with polynomials. Basically if $P(x)=a_n(x-r)^n+a_{n-1}(x-r)^{n-1}+...+a_1(x-r)+a_0$ it can be shown, algebraically, that 
$$a_n=\frac{P^{(n)}(r)}{n!}$$
Of course, the concept of the nth derivative isn't actually introduced, $P^{(n)}$ represents the nth application of the power rule to $P$. So I was wondering if this theory can be extended to rational functions: $f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials. Obviously, 
$$f'(x)=\frac{P'(x)}{Q(x)}-\frac{P(x)Q'(x)}{Q(x)^2}$$ 
But I was wondering if its possible to derive this with an extension of the same algebraic method-it seems to me that it would be necessary to prove the chain and product rule, but of course I'd be glad to hear if there's another way.

Comment: Formal differentiation of (formal) rational functions works fine. You can just take your formula for $f'(x)$ as the definition and prove the chain rule and product rule from it. Another approach to formal derivatives of (formal) rational functions would be via formal Laurent series (in that approach your formula would be proved as the formal equivalent of the quotient rule).

Comment: @RobArthan Why would a Laurent series be relevant when considering functions $f: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$?